# How to add the User Assigned Identity to Azure Synapse Workspace using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to assign User Assigned Managed identity to Azure Synapse

I have the following Terraform Code

```
// Create synapse User Assigned Identity
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "uai_synapse" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location

  name = var.uai_synapse
}

// Create Synapse Workspace
resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "synapsews" {
  name                                 = var.dat_synapse_ws
  resource_group_name                  = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  location                             = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.datalake-config.id
  sql_identity_control_enabled         = true
  sql_administrator_login              = var.synapse_sql_administrator_login
  sql_administrator_login_password     = var.synapse_sql_administrator_login_password
  managed_virtual_network_enabled      = true

  aad_admin {
    login = data.azuread_user.user.mail
    object_id = data.azuread_user.user.object_id
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  }
  
  identity {
    type         = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_account.datalake ]
}
```

But I don't see any option to Assign the User Assigned Identity to Azure Synapse Workspace, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, you cannot do it:

[image: identity]
Source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/synapse_workspace#principal_id